# Any up to date functional languages?

Tags: functional-programming, programming-languages

I just discovered functional languages, and they look awesome. For example, you can essentially do:

```
fib(0)=0
fib(1)=1
fib(x)=fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)
```

to define a function. The problem is, it doesn't look like any are being actively developed our have good support. Are there any good functional languages that aren't dead?

Comment: I didn't know [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell) was dead.

Comment: I think the question is for the comic effect.

Comment: Or I was terribly uneducated.  By the way, I settled for Haskell. I guess the outdated website and blog threw me off.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any good functional languages that aren't dead?

There are many. Look into Haskell, Scala, Clojure, and F#. Click [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages_by_type#Functional_languages) for a larger list.

Answer (score 2):

> It doesn't look like any are being actively developed our have good
>   support.

- [F#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh388569.aspx) by Microsoft is my personal favorite. [The F# Software Foundation](http://fsharp.org/) is a good place to start. - [StackOverflow Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/f#)
- [OCaml](http://ocaml.org/) is used in the real world by [Jane Street](http://janestreet.com/technology/) and to develop [Proof Assistants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_assistant)
  such as [HOL Light](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jrh13/hol-light/), Cog. - [StackOverflow Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ocaml)
- [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/) is becoming quite popular but I don't know if it used outside of the academic community. - [StackOverflow Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell)
- [Standard ML of New Jersey](http://www.smlnj.org/) - [StackOverflow Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sml)
- [Mercury](http://www.mercurylang.org/) which also supports logic, think Prolog. [Mercury user group](http://lists.mercurylang.org/pipermail/users/)
- [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) - [StackOverflow Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala)
- [Clojure](http://clojure.org/) - [StackOverflow Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clojure)
- [Erlang](http://www.erlang.org/) - [StackOverflow Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erlang)

If you have a look at the StackOverflow tag: [functional-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/functional-programming) look at all of the other languages associated with that tag.

i.e. C#, JavaScript, R, Agda, MatLab, C++, Python, PHP. I don't know all of these languages so I am not sure how much they can do functional programming.

Comment: Do you know any modern haskell IDE? GHC looks old.

Comment: @GuyCoder this looks like the right answer but you need to do more research. OCaml is used in more than one company, and Haskell is used in many companies, probably even in more companies than OCaml because if its academic exposure, although OCaml is closer to mainstream languages. Scala is poised to be the most popular, but it is not a "functional first" language. OCaml is my personal favorite.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked Scala ? There is active storm community behind it. Infact lot of very tech focused companies are re-writing their software in Scala ( e.g Twitter ).

Comment: Yes -- for someone really concerned about mainstream acceptance, Scala is the best suggestion, unless they are in .NET / Mono environment, then F#.

Answer (score 1):

Haskell, Lisp, and Erlang, depending on what you are wanting to accomplish.  Scala is described as a hybrid object/functional language.  It is said that Scala can be used to write code purely in one paradigm or the other.

Comment: And OCaml. http://ocaml.org/